# Meteor: Updating multiple profile values

Tags: javascript, meteor

It is very straightforward implementation but may be there is some problem with my syntax here:

```
Template.userProfilePage.events({
    'submit #profile-page': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var name = template.find('#fullName').value,
        address = template.find('#address').value,
        company = template.find('#company').value,
        otherField = template.find('#other').value;

        alert(name);

        Meteor.users.update(
            { _id:Meteor.user()._id },
            { 
                $set: {
                    "profile.name":name,
                    "profile.address":address,
                    "profile.company":company,
                    "profile.other":other
                }
            },
            { upsert: true },
            { multi: true }
        );

        return false;
    }
});
```

Template contains normal html pages. It always throws error:

> `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re updating only one user, there’s no need for `multi: true`. There should also never be a need to upsert; if you’re working with a logged-in user, there should always be a document for them in the `users` collection. Try something like this:

```
Meteor.users.update(
  Meteor.userId(),
  {$set: {
     "profile.name": name,
     "profile.address": address,
     "profile.company": company,
     "profile.other": other
    }
  }
);
```

Also make sure your `allow` and `deny` rules permit you to do this update.

P.S. I suspect your error message is probably because you have `{ multi: true }` as the fourth argument to `.update`. Per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#update), the syntax is `collection.update(selector, modifier, [options], [callback])`; so if you ever want to use both `multi` and `upsert`, combine them into one object in the third argument: `{ multi: true, upsert: true }` (you can also just use `collection.upsert` instead of `.update`). Your error is probably caused by you sending an object, `{ multi: true }`, as the fourth argument instead of the callback function that `update` is expecting.

Comment: Still getting the same error. How would I check for the `allow` and `deny`?

Comment: There is one more thing, few of the values may be `insert` not `update`. Thats why I had `{upset: true}` in my code.

Comment: Upsert only applies to entire documents, not individual fields; see http://docs.meteor.com/#upsert. Are you sure that `name`, `address` etc. are all valid? Did you fix the arguments like I described in my P.S.?

Comment: Yes I have removed `{multi: true}` argument from my `update` call.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306385/meteor-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-on-keypress-event. One of your variables `name`, `address` etc. is probably an object rather than a string. Try replacing `template.find('#fullName').value` with `$('#fullName').val()`, and make sure to validate that they're all strings before you run the `update`.