# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in Meteor

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

Getting this error while trying to use code below:

```
Session.set("MyTemplate_Instance",Template.instance());
```

I am trying to store a Template Instance into the session variable is it supported by meteor?

Trying to do something like,

**Template 1**

`Session.set("MyTemplate_Instance",Template.instance());`

**Template 2**

`Template.instance() = Session.get("MyTemplate_Instance")`

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when you pass large object as an argument to a method. Do you really want the have all the template instance in your Session variable ?

Example: If you want to store the template data, you should store only the data like this :

```
Session.set("MyTemplateData", Template.instance().data);
```

Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18691480/4601487

Comment: Thanks @Gaëtan Rouziès 
I want to set view of one template to another template is there any possible way to do this?

Comment: Sorry i don't understand "to set view of one template to another template". Can you explain it again ? You want to update a template helper (used to update the view) from another template ?

Comment: I want to create a replica of current template into another template, like we copy one object into another object. So is it possible to create a copy of one template into another?

I want to do something like, 

**Template 1**
`Session.set("MyTemplate_Instance",Template.instance());`

**Template 2**
`Template.instance() = Session.get("MyTemplate_Instance")`

Comment: This is the wrong way to do so, to have a replicate you need to pass to the second template the same datacontext than the first template. And if you load data from Database or Session, it's already shared between template.

Template inclusion 1 : `{{> myTemplate myDataContext}}`
Template inclusion 2 : `{{> myTemplate myDataContext}}`
If they have the same datacontext, you already have replica.

Comment: Ok, actually I'm trying to change the position of a template from one container to another on triggering an event. without destroying/ Re-rendering it..

So, thought this way it will work..